# Find all palindromes in the danish language

Tags: c++, performance, vectors

I made a program to attempt to find all palindromes in the danish language. Words.txt contains about 50.000 lines of danish words. Palindromes.txt is empty initially.

Im running the program on a Intel® Core™ m3-7Y30 Processor - which has a base frequency of 1.00 GHz. Seeing as the program - as it currently stands - has to check 50.000 * 50.000 = 2.500.000.000 words, it is really slow. Ive been running it for about 25 minutes now without a result (unsuprisingly). I am fairly new to C++, and so I have no idea how to optimize this.

Thats why im posting here - any tips on how to optimize the speed of the program would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

std::string read_file(const std::string& path)
{
    std::ifstream file(path);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldent open file!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::string content = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    if (content.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldent read file content" << std::endl;
    }
    return content;
}

std::vector<std::string> split_words(const std::string& words_string)
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    words.reserve(50000);
    std::stringstream ss_word(words_string);
    std::string word;
    while (!ss_word.eof())
    {
        ss_word >> word;
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    return words;
}

std::vector<std::string> find_palinedromes(const std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    std::vector<std::string> palindromes;
    std::string first_word = std::string();
    std::string second_word = std::string();

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); ++j)
        {
            first_word = words[i];
            second_word = words[j];
            std::reverse(first_word.begin(), first_word.end());

            if (first_word == second_word)
            {
                if (std::find(palindromes.begin(), palindromes.end(), first_word) == palindromes.end())
                {
                    palindromes.push_back(first_word);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return palindromes;
}

void write_to_file(const std::string& path, const std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    std::ofstream file(path);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldent open file!" << std::endl;
    }
    for (const std::string& word : words)
    {
        file << word + "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::string words_string = read_file("C:/Users/A/source/repos/Bresenhams/Bresenhams/src/Words.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> words = split_words(words_string);
    std::vector<std::string> palindromes = find_palinedromes(words);
    write_to_file("C:/Users/A/source/repos/Bresenhams/Bresenhams/src/Palindromes.txt", palindromes);
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Found all palindromes in: " << duration.count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a double loop checking against all other words to determine if something is a palindrome. This is unnecessary. You can look at a single word and determine if it is a palindrome, by reversing it. This should reduce the number of checks by a factor of n.

You should also prefer using a range for to a raw for-loop.

find_palindromes can then become something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> find_palindromes(const std::vector<std::string>& words)
{
    for (const std::string& word : words )
    {
        std::string reverseWord(word);
        std::reverse(reverseWord.begin(), reverseWord.end());

        if (word == reverseWord)
        {
            if (std::find(palindromes.begin(), palindromes.end(), first_word) == palindromes.end())
            {
                palindromes.push_back(first_word);
            }
        }
     }

    return palindromes;
}
```

Comment: Waw, no idea why I thought I needed two words.. This is optimal, thank you!